# How to deal with a missing key in a hashmap

Tags: c

What might be a proper error or return code for when a `key` is asked for that cannot be returned?

```
void hash_delete(hash_table* table, const char* key)
{
    hash_item* item = hash_get(table, key);
    if (item == NULL)
        ; // what error to raise?
    else
        delete_hash_item_internal(item);
}
```

My thoughts were either to make the function return a `bool` instead (1=found, 0=not found), or do an `exit()`. What do you think would be a proper way to handle this?

Comment: By design that kind of function usually just return a value signaling the entry wasn't found Whether you exit from application or do nothing, is usually up to the caller.

Comment: A golden rule in signalling errors is " can the signalee take any sort of action on the error? "; if not, better to abort; if so, better to signal an error.  In libc, for instance, open() returns an error if the named file could not be accessed in the prescribed manner; thus open can be used to probe for files.  Lseek, when provided with a `whence` that is none of `SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END` raises a signal on the caller.  The implication is that there is not reasonable correction for seeking from an undefined spot.  And, it is way too easy to transpose the 2nd and 3rd arguments to lseek().

Comment: ps: is there a bonus point for filling exactly the maximum space for a comment?

Comment: @Jack like a `bool` for succeeded/failed, or are there usually multiple error codes for a function like this?

Comment: @tadman yea probably not, a missing key doesn't really seem like a big issue and the caller can figure out how to deal with that...

Comment: I'd expect a delete on a non-existent key to be a no-op, as in it doesn't do anything. It **especially** does not crash the program on purpose. If you want to return a "did delete something" indicator, or "number of things deleted" response, that could be useful. In other words, return an `int` representing "keys deleted".

Comment: @tadman yea here the keys are unique so it'd either be 1 (deleted) or 0 (not deleted).

Comment: I would not do anything if the key does not exist. The result state is that the key is not in the hashmap, which the caller intended. If they wanted to know whether the key was in the hashmap before, they should have checked for it.

Comment: @Cheatah so would you return `void` or `bool` or `int` from the function then?

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities, as you are the one who is designing the function. However, calling `exit()` is not a good choice, as it forces always the same radical behavior of the function. It is better to leave the caller the right to decide to stop the program, continue, log something, etc. (as has been already pointed in comments to the OP).
So I would choose to return different value when the key exist and when it does not. You can choose between the following:

- Return a simple `bool`. Return `true` when key is found (deleted). Return `false` when key not found. The most simple and easy to understand behavior.
- Return a `char*`. Return `NULL` when key is found (deleted). Return the `key` itself when it is not found. This method allows possible further action taken directly with the result. This may be useful, for example, if the key is obtained from a function and there is no need to store in a variable unless this function fails.
- Return a `hash_item*`. Return the `item` variable when the key is found. Return `NULL` when key is not found. This is one of the most typical behaviors in deleting functions, and it allows to use the returned value of the `delete` function directly as `get`+`delete` avoiding a separate call. Note this method may have some issues depending on how the `hash_table` is implemented. For example, if it contains pointers to `hash_item` might therefore contain "valid" `NULL` values and those can be interpreted as deleting function not finding entry instead of finding entry containing `NULL`. Also may be problematic to return the `item` if the `delete_hash_item_internal()` function frees memory from the pointer stored in the table (which you will return) or something similar.

If I had to choose, I would prefer the last option (if it is possible due to issues I mentioned). If it is not possible I would use the first one for the sake of simplicity. But at the end is up to you as designer to decide which one is better, taking also into account the rest of the code you will need and how you want the function to be used.